# InAppBrowser for Ionic Not Working

Tags: cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

I'm trying to use the Cordova plugin to enable in-app-browser. It's just a very simple proof of concept I am trying to put together but all I get is;

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for InAppBrowser: (?, ?, ?).
```

My home.ts file is;

```
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [InAppBrowser]
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    }
    launch(url) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=true");
        });
    }
}
```

And my html file includes;

```
<button (click)="launch('https://www.example.com')">Launch URL</button>
```

I have virtually no experience of mobile development I am really just trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/launch-websites-with-ionic-2-using-the-inappbrowser/).

I have Googled around, [found this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-find-name-cordova/52650/5), and have tried installing;

```
npm install -g typings
typings install dt~cordova --save --global
```

But it's still not working. How can I get this working?

Comment: Have you tried with `'location=yes'` instead of `'location=true'`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I got directed here after having the same issue following a tutorial that seems a little outdated.

For anyone having similar problems, using .open() is deprecated with ionic native, and the correct way to use the inAppBrowser is as follows:

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser(Url, "_blank");
```

Which will open within the apps browser. You can use _system to open in the default device browser, such as safari on iOS:

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser(Url, "_system");
```

Everything else in your above example appears to be correct.